# Local-to-remote replication times out or replicates only few documents CouchDb

Tags: curl, docker, couchdb, replication, connection-timeout

I run couchdb installed in Docker (klaemo/couchdb), and have port forwarded the installation so it is available to my local machine. I have not configured this database aside from adding an admin user.

These are my vm port forwarding settings:
[image]

I can open localhost:5984/_utils, browse the data in the installation, and I can instantiate a replication from my remote database in AWS down to this couchDB, but if I initiate a replication the other way, it never updates in Futon (all I get is spinner in the menu bar).

If I do the replication with Curl, like so:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d '{"source":"http://username:password@localhost:5984/database-name","target":"http://username:password@remote.url.com:5984/database-name","connection_timeout":"60000"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get a timeout.

```
{"error":"timeout"}
```

If I open Charles (a HTTP proxy) and add "proxy":"http://localhost:8888" to the curl request payload, no traffic ever appears, so I assume the connection is never even attempted between local couch and remote couch.

Any ideas why this is?

**Edit**

Note that the curl replication is executed inside a shell in the docker container. I am able to create new databases fine on both local and remote databases from the same container, only replication times out.

**Edit 2**
After some trial and error, I get the replication to run, but it only replicates a subset of documents:

Response after running replication cURL:

`{"ok":true,"session_id":"3c195aa3c723696bfb33679d4de3632a","source_last_seq":79,"replication_id_version":3,"history":[{"session_id":"3c195aa3c723696bfb33679d4de3632a","start_time":"Mon, 20 Apr 2015 13:42:37 GMT","end_time":"Mon, 20 Apr 2015 13:42:38 GMT","start_last_seq":0,"end_last_seq":79,"recorded_seq":79,"missing_checked":53,"missing_found":53,"docs_read":53,"docs_written":**53**,"doc_write_failures":0}]}`

the target DB was an empty DB, so it should replicate all documents. This, by the way is the result of cURL'in the local origin DB:

`{"db_name":"db-name","doc_count":**435**,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":43116,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":384835704,"data_size":7091262,"instance_start_time":"1429537029129810","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":43116}`

So it should have replicated 435 documents and not 53.

I thought if I ran the replication again it would continue the process, but it did not run (no_changes: true):

`{"ok":true,"no_changes":true,"session_id":"3c195aa3c723696bfb33679d4de3632a","source_last_seq":79,"replication_id_version":3,"history":[{"session_id":"3c195aa3c723696bfb33679d4de3632a","start_time":"Mon, 20 Apr 2015 13:42:37 GMT","end_time":"Mon, 20 Apr 2015 13:42:38 GMT","start_last_seq":0,"end_last_seq":79,"recorded_seq":79,"missing_checked":53,"missing_found":53,"docs_read":53,"docs_written":53,"doc_write_failures":0}]}`

Comment: What do you get with `curl http://username:password@remote.url.com:5984` from within the docker container shell?

Comment: That call works fine - I get the welcome JSON from couchDB. I tried again and the replication worked actually - except it only replicated 53 of my 435 documents? Maybe there is a strict timeout that cuts off the process? The next time I call replication it won't run ("no changes"). I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?